# Preventing users from registering with xxx@yyy format email address

Tags: 6, emails, forms

Drupal seems to let users register with emails like `xxx@yyy`

I heard that this kind of email address can exist.
But I want users to register with only emails like `xxx@yyy.zzz`

Is there any way to validate this type of email format and prevent users from registering with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a core function named: [function valid_email_address](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/valid_email_address/6) that will check that the syntax is valid.

Example of use:

```
$mail = $form_state['values']['submitted_tree']['email_address'];
if (!valid_email_address($mail)) {
  form_set_error('[submitted][email_address]', t('The email address appears to be invalid.'));
}
```

Comment: Tanks I'll try that!